# Java, MySQL updating table using ID (primary key)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I have a program in which working with MySql and Java JDBC.

My question is:

I have a table (`TEMP`) with `ID` as only 1 column and another table with user personal details like ID, name, age etc..

Im trying to retrieve the `ID` from `TEMP` table and update unfilled information like name, age, address etc in `USER` table.

This is the query I wrote:

```
update m_auth_info 
set name  = '"+name+"', 
    addr  = '"+addr+"', 
    email = '"+email+"', 
    affiliation = '"+affil+"', 
    status = '"+1+"'  
where a_id = '"+ResultSet+"'";
```

and when my `getIdMethod` retrieves ID into `ResultSet` from `TEMP` table. I couldn't able to update `USER` TABLE.

But it works if I give ID directly.. example.

```
update m_auth_info 
set name = '"+name+"', 
    addr = '"+addr+"', 
    email = '"+email+"', 
    affiliation = '"+affil+"', 
    status = '"+1+"'  
where a_id = '"+8989+"'";
```

Please tell me if I have to write which step to write in my `getIdMethod`, so that ill get the value into `ResultSet`.

Comment: Where is the `getIdMethod` method that you are using? is it a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int id=0;
String sql = "Select ID from Temp";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next(){
   id = rs.getInt(1);
  /*   pass your update query here and use like this it should work for you
    update m_auth_info  set name  = '"+name+"',
    addr  = '"+addr+"',  email = '"+email+"', 
    affiliation = '"+affil+"', status = '"+1+"'  where a_id = '"+id+"'";*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is to get the result from `ResultSet`, which you can do with something `rs.getLong(0)`, your `ResultSet variable`.`getYourIdType`(`0`) or `columnName`

Comment: Im sry I just gave my update query here. My getIdMethod has these statements                                                              public void getIdMehod (String sql){                                     ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql); }                                    and I passed this statement -- String sql = "select * from TEMP";    This TEMP table will have only one ID which is 8989.